# 'there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table' where i dont want something to be unique

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres I have written the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE students (
    student_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(15),
    surname VARCHAR(35),
    enrollment_year INT);

CREATE TABLE teachers (
    bsn BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(15),
    surname VARCHAR(35),
    salary REAL,
    scale INT,
    CONSTRAINT salary CHECK(salary < (25 * scale) AND salary > (20 * scale))
    );

CREATE TABLE course (
    course_code VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    course_name VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE,
    study_points INT);

CREATE TABLE study_program (
    course_name VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    level VARCHAR(15),
    duration VARCHAR(10),
    FOREIGN KEY(course_name) REFERENCES course(course_name));

CREATE TABLE assignment (
    assignment_code VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE,
    course_name VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(assignment_code, course_name),
    FOREIGN KEY(course_name) REFERENCES course(course_name)
    );

CREATE TABLE records (
    student_id BIGINT,
    course_name VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(student_id, course_name),
    FOREIGN KEY(student_id) REFERENCES students(student_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(course_name) REFERENCES course(course_name));

CREATE TABLE make (
    student_id BIGINT,
    assignment_code VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(student_id, assignment_code),
    FOREIGN KEY(student_id) REFERENCES students(student_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(assignment_code) REFERENCES assignment(assignment_code));

CREATE TABLE prerequisit (
    assignment_code VARCHAR(20),
    course_name VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(assignment_code, course_name),
    FOREIGN KEY(assignment_code) REFERENCES assignment(assignment_code),
    FOREIGN KEY(course_name) REFERENCES course(course_name)
    );

CREATE TABLE records_2 (
    assignment_code VARCHAR(20),
    course_name VARCHAR(20),
    bsn BIGINT,
    mandatory BOOLEAN,
    year INT,
    week INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(assignment_code, course_name),
    FOREIGN KEY(assignment_code) REFERENCES assignment(assignment_code),
    FOREIGN KEY(course_name) REFERENCES course(course_name)
    );

CREATE TABLE designes (
    course_code VARCHAR(15),
    bsn BIGINT,
    study_points INT,
    course_name VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(course_code, bsn),
    FOREIGN KEY(course_code) REFERENCES course(course_code),
    FOREIGN KEY(bsn) REFERENCES teachers(bsn),
    FOREIGN KEY(study_points) REFERENCES course(study_points),
    FOREIGN KEY(course_name) REFERENCES course(course_name)
    );

CREATE TABLE reviews (
    bsn BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    course_code VARCHAR(15),
    study_points INT,
    course_name VARCHAR(20),
    FOREIGN KEY(bsn) REFERENCES teachers(bsn),
    FOREIGN KEY(course_code) REFERENCES course(course_code),
    FOREIGN KEY(study_points) REFERENCES course(study_points),
    FOREIGN KEY(course_name) REFERENCES course(course_name)
    );
```

The error I get is

> ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "course"

This error is fixed by adding the UNIQUE constraint to study points, however I do not want study points to be unique because I need different courses to have the same amount of study points.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+ERROR%3A+there+is+no+unique+constraint+matching+given+keys+for+referenced+table+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing `study_points` makes no sense whatsoever. In fact referencing three different columns of a single table makes no sense whatsoever.

You **only** need `FOREIGN KEY(course_code) REFERENCES course(course_code)` and you don't need the columns `course_name`  and `study_points` in the `reviews` table as they are implicitly defined through the foreign key to the `course` table.

Which means the table should look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE reviews 
(
    bsn BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    course_code VARCHAR(15),
    FOREIGN KEY(bsn) REFERENCES teachers(bsn),
    FOREIGN KEY(course_code) REFERENCES course(course_code)
);
```

Which then begs the question: what is that table supposed to do? You can only have a single row per teacher in there because `bsn` is the primary key (thus can't be repeated). So that is a one-to-one (or one-to-zero/one) relationship. Which in turn means you could move the column `course_code` to the teachers table, e.g. as `reviewed_course`.

However, I *guess* you meant to create a many-to-many relationship between `teachers` and `course` which then should be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE reviews 
(
    bsn BIGINT,
    course_code VARCHAR(15),
    primary key (bsn, course_code),
    FOREIGN KEY(bsn) REFERENCES teachers(bsn),
    FOREIGN KEY(course_code) REFERENCES course(course_code)
);
```

That makes the *combination* of `bsn` and `course_code` unique. Which means each teacher can review each course exactly once, but a teacher can review multiple courses and a single course can be reviewed by multiple teachers.